# Makefile optimization

Tags: makefile

I am a newbie for Makefile. Optimizing my code Makefile code.

I have following code which is messy, Is there any better way of writing this.(for more clarity added space before each line)

```
ifdef X
  ifndef Y
    LNFLAGS + = -m32
  else
        ifndef Z
            LNFLAGS + = -m32
        endif
  endif
endif
```

Comment: I guess you could have separate target rules instead of this logic. Maybe you should explain the context more. Hard to tell from this fragment for me at least.

Comment: Here we have a Makefile Basing on environmental varaibles we have to add specific files like with following logic
if in env variables 
1.) X not defined then ignore
2.) X is defined
     i.) If Y is not defined, then add LDFLAG     
     ii.) If y is defined
           a.) check Z is not defined

Comment: Does `LNFLAGS += $(and $X,$(or $Y$Z,-m32))` do what you want?